# Почему выводит, что $a max, если оно false, и, по идее, не должно быть выполнено условие?

Tags: php

Почему при начальных условиях выводит, что $a это max?

```
$b=400;
$c=300;
$a=350;
$d = ($b > $c && $b > $a) ? true : false;
$e = ($a > $c && $a > $b) ? true : false;
$f = ($c > $a && $c > $b) ? true : false;
if ($e=true){
    echo "$a is max";
}
elseif ($d=true){
    echo "$b is max";
}
else {
    echo "$c is max";
}
```

Comment: Потому что у вас `if ($e=true)` вместо `if ($e == true)` (или более короткое `if ($e)`)

Comment: Основы языка: знаком `=` обозначается присваивание, знаком `==` (а также `===`) — проверка на равенство.

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит освежить в памяти те книжки по PHP, которые вы прочли.

Comment: Спасибо , я сейчас только начал все это учить)

Answer (score 1):

У вас неправильное "равно". Нужно так:

```
if ($e==true){
    echo "$a is max";
}
elseif ($d==true){
    echo "$b is max";
}
else {
    echo "$c is max";
}
```

Или даже так, для любой переменной, содержащей true-false:

```
if ($e){
    echo "$a is max";
}
elseif ($d){
    echo "$b is max";
}
else {
    echo "$c is max";
}
```

А ещё лучше называть переменные осмысленно. Ну и минутка теории:

Одинарный знак `=` - это присваивание, двойной `==` - сравнение без учёта типа переменной (например, целое число 1 равно дробному числу 1.0), а тройной `===` учитывает и тип.

P.S. Заметили, как ваше условие удачно оптимизировало ваш код? Переменная $f в нём не пригодилась :)

Comment: Спасибо) Уже разобрался)